# Executing a .bat file from PowerShell is not working

Tags: powershell

I have a working PowerShell script that generates JSON file and converts them to CSV. Running well when executed manually via ISE. However, I noticed that when I execute the script via Task Scheduler, the generation of JSON files are working correctly but somehow skips the part where it converts to CSV. I'm using a .bat file that was given to me to convert JSON to CSV and I just call that .bat on my PS script.

I have read somewhere that this could be because I'm trying to start a process without an interactive session and that this could be fixed by checking "Run only when the user is logged on" but I'm still getting the same result.

> $path = "C:\Apps\ActiveMQanalysis\ConvertJsonFiletoCSV.bat"
>
> Start-Process -FilePath $path
>
> Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

Edit: This is the content of the batch file:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" -cp lib*
>   de.znt.activeMqAnalysis.BrokerStatistics C:\Apps\brokerResults\

Edit: As pointed out by most users here, I did add some logging on the .bat file to see where the error is coming from. As it turned out, it is giving me an error that it cant find or load main class `de.znt.activeMqAnalysis.BrokerStatistics`.

Comment: powershell can convert JSON files to CSV. have you tried looking into the CSV & JSON cmdlets in PoSh?

Comment: Can you paste the content of the bat file?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i think the JSON file converter I'm using is specifically formatted for our needs. This is the reason why I needed to run that .bat file to convert such.

Comment: @Moerwald I have updated the question to include the contents of the bat file.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue (check what user is setup in Task Scheduler to run the process)... but it seems really weird, you're using PS to run a BAT, to call a Java library, to accomplish something PS already does natively.

Comment: I agree with @JoelCoehoorn that this is probably a permissions issue. It's probably related to the user account not being able to access the folders, the user account not being able to execute as a batch, or to Java thinking it's interactive and it's arguing with Task Scheduler. Alternately, you might be in the wrong directory or using a user account that doesn't know anything about your java program's classpath. Or it's some kind of classpath hell. In any case, I seriously doubt that it's Powershell. It's Java and Task Scheduler (i.e., Windows security) failing to agree on reality.

Comment: @Mariyah - ah! thank you for that info. that java app you are running from the BAT file seems likely to be part of your problem ... have you added any logging to the BAT file & the java file to confirm if either of them is being loaded or run? have you tried running the java directly from inside PoSh?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you are right that it is a permission issue. I have updated the question for everyone's reference as I still dont know how to fix it. Thank you so much. I really appreciate this.

Comment: @BaconBits you are right about the permission as well. I have updated the question for reference.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey adding a logging to the BAT file helped a lot. it turns out to be a permission issue. i still dont know how to fix it though. but thank you so much.

Comment: @Mariyah - you are most welcome! glad to know you were able to trace the problem somewhat. [*grin*] ///// i would do two things ... [1] add some more logging to determine the effective permissions at various points in your code. [2] try running the java stuff _directly_ from inside  PoSh instead of using the BAT fie.

Answer (score 1):

Start-Process runs things in the background by default.  Why don't you run it directly?

```
C:\Apps\ActiveMQanalysis\ConvertJsonFiletoCSV.bat
```

Or with a variable you can use the call operator:

```
& $path
```

Comment: I tried doing this but same results. For some reason, the bat file was not executed when I do this in Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the bat file takes longer than 5 seconds. Your call to `Start-Process` immediately returns. You can add the `-Wait` switch to add blocking behaviour to `Start-Process`. Change the code to:

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Apps\ActiveMQanalysis\ConvertJsonFiletoCSV.bat' -Wait -Passthru
$process.ExitCode
```

`-PassThru` returns a process object that will give you detailed information like the exit code of the process. Further information can be found in the `Start-Process` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6).

Comment: This isn't the case, @Moerwald. The task completed successfully based on its Status and yet I can't see the generated CSV. I was under the same assumption as you at first but I'm still getting the same result.